# Facebook XFBML after login, get user information through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, facebook, xfbml

I use the XFBML Facebook login button to authenticate the user. After users entered correct password. How do I use `FB.Facebook.apiClient` or any related JavaScript to get user logined information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to init this function at begining. like this:

```
FB.init("APIKEY","/xd_receiver.htm",
    {"reloadIfSessionStateChanged": true,"ifUserConnected":onFBConnected});


function onFBConnected(){
var api = FB.Facebook.apiClient;
var uid = [api.get_session().uid];
var fields = ["name"];
api.users_getInfo(uid, fields, function(result){

    alert(result[0].name);      

});
```

}

solved my problem I hope it helps.